# Seaborn barplot color_palette not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm seeing a weird behavior with a Seaborn barplot. I am using a script that I verified that it works with one data frame. When I concatenate multiple data frames and use `groupby`, the barplot is coming out white, i.e., the `color_palette` is no longer working.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection as p
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(font_scale=1.5, style='white', context='paper')

def plot_consumers(count, df):
    print(count.groupby(['periods'], as_index=False)[
                    'consumerId'].mean().describe())
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 3))
    pal = sns.color_palette('Blues_d', n_colors=1)

    sns.barplot(x='periods',
                y='consumerId',
                data=count.groupby(['periods'], as_index=False)[
                    'consumerId'].mean(),
                ax=axes[0],
                palette=pal)

    sns.lineplot(x='periods',
                 y='distance',
                 data=df.groupby(['periods'], as_index=False)[
                     'distance'].mean(),
                 legend=False,
                 ax=axes[1])

    # Axes config
    axes[0].set(ylim=(-0.05, 100.05))
    axes[0].set(ylabel='%')
    axes[0].set(xlim=(-10, 310))
    axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))
    axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    axes[1].set(ylabel='customer satisfaction')
    axes[1].set(ylim=(-0.05, 1.05))

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

After I group the `count` data frame, I get the following:

```
          periods  consumerId
count  300.000000  300.000000
mean   149.500000   21.540741
std     86.746758    0.175113
min      0.000000   19.666667
25%     74.750000   21.555556
50%    149.500000   21.555556
75%    224.250000   21.555556
max    299.000000   23.111111
```

I know that the bars are being plotted because I changed the style to `dark` and I can see the bars in white.

If I change the barplot to a lineplot it also works.

Here's the plot with `barplot` and `dark` style:
[image]

Here's the plot with `lineplot` and `white` style:
[image]

Comment: After some try and error, the line that is causing the issue is the aesthetics:  `sns.set(font_scale=1.5, style='white', context='paper')`. Still investigating how to use both (or style my plot as I want to

Answer (score 0):

According to @mwaskom, the issue is because I'm trying to fit too many bars in a short space.